# Is there a way to copy an Excel formula with an anchor cell and have the anchor update every n rows?

Tags: excel, copy, anchor, fill, large-files

I have a large data set I'm working with where I'm trying to find the smallest *n* related to a mean of a set of samples that falls below the lower bound of a given confidence interval.

Example: Does the mean of all samples where *n* = 45 fall below the lower bound of the confidence interval for samples with *n* = 50?

I'm doing this with the following formula in Excel:

=IF(U2<=$Z$2,D2,"NO") - where U2 = mean, Z2 = the lower bound of the confidence interval, D2 = *n* if true.

I have Z2 anchored since it is the target lower bound for the first set of 150 rows, but the next 150 rows has a new target (Z152).

Is there a way to copy this formula down the intended column where it will autofill the next anchor cell every 150 rows?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I appreciate the reply. That doesn't seem to be working though - it's giving me a #SPILL error for the first set of 150, and then for the rest of the dataset it's hit or miss on whether or not it's returning the correct output (e.g., returning "NO" when the mean value is in fact less than the lower bound of the CI referenced in the Z column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` to reference a cell in a column, and calculate the row number any way you choose.

Like this

```
=IF(U18<=INDEX(Z:Z, (INT((ROW() - 1) / 150) * 150 + 2)),D18,"NO")
```

If you want, you can replace `150` with a cell reference containing the row increment value, and/or `2` with cell reference containing the first row number

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. Saved me 6000+ instances of having to change that anchor number.